# Render a form partially when click on a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I am trying to associate each post with the set of  tags.
A user can create or select tags while creating posts. I have used nested attributes for creating tags at post controller.
This is my view page in the **posts_controller** for creating new form.

```
  <label>Title </label><br/><%= form.text_field :title, required: true %><br/><br/>
      <label>Content </label> <br/> <%= form.text_area :content, required: true %><br/><br/>
      <%#= collection_check_boxes(:posts, :tags, @tags, :id, :name) %>
      <label>Tags </label><br/>
      <%=form.collection_select(:tag_ids, Tag.all, :id, :name, {}, :multiple => true) %><br/><br/>
        <%= form.fields_for :tags do |tag_form| %>
          <label>Tag name </label><%= tag_form.text_field :name%><br/>
        <% end %>
      <%= form.submit %>
```

I just want to add a link 'create new tag' so that while clicking on a link will load a form to create a new tag partially at the new or edit page of the post. How can I do that?

Comment: if you are looking for nested fields, try cocoon gem https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [Cocoon Gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon). That's what it does.

Answer (score 0):

The `Cocoon` gem is one option but a cleaner option is to use the Form Object pattern where you can encapsulate your nested logic:

-https://revs.runtime-revolution.com/creating-form-objects-with-activemodel-346e6c2abbf3
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects